# How to prevent Z3 solver from binding (=interpreting) certain variables (=constants) when satisfiability is checked?

Tags: c#, z3

Is there a way to prevent the Z3 solver from binding (=interpreting) certain variables (=constants) when satisfiability is checked?

For example, in the following C# program two different interpretations are possible:

1. switch1=true and CONST1=16, or
2. switch2=true and RAX!0=16

`

```
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "unsat-core", "true" },    // enable generation of unsat cores
    { "model", "true" },         // enable model generation
    { "proof", "false" }         // enable proof generation
};
Context ctx = new Context(settings);
Solver solver = ctx.MkSolver();

BitVecExpr rax0 = ctx.MkBVConst("RAX!0", 64); // register values
BitVecExpr rax1 = ctx.MkBVConst("RAX!1", 64);
BoolExpr switch1 = ctx.MkBoolConst("switch_1_on"); // switch on/off instruction 1
BoolExpr switch2 = ctx.MkBoolConst("switch_2_on"); // switch on/off instruction 2
BitVecExpr immConst = ctx.MkBVConst("CONST1", 64); // imm const

//making rax0 inconsistent does not work
//solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rax0, ctx.MkBVAND(ctx.MkBV(0, 64), ctx.MkBV(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 64))));

// instruction 1: MOV RAX, immConst
solver.Assert(ctx.MkIff(switch1, ctx.MkEq(rax1, immConst)));

// instruction 2: NOP
solver.Assert(ctx.MkIff(switch2, ctx.MkEq(rax1, rax0)));

// atleast and atmost one instruction must be executed
solver.Assert(ctx.MkAtMost(new BoolExpr[] { switch1, switch2 }, 1));
solver.Assert(ctx.MkOr(new BoolExpr[] { switch1, switch2 }));

// after executing the ASM we want rax to be 0
solver.Assert(ctx.MkEq(rax1, ctx.MkBV(0, 64)));
```

`

**Question**: Is there a natural way to make the second interpretation (switch2=true) invalid such that it will not show up when iterating over all interpretations.

I've tried to make rax0 inconsistent by asserting `ctx.MkEq(rax0, ctx.MkBVAND(ctx.MkBV(0, 64), ctx.MkBV(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 64))` but that didn't help.

I could check whether interpretations use `rax0` somehow, but i don't know how to test that. I guess it would have been better that such interpretations were made invalid.

Comment: You could assert the negation of switch2. eg.

         solver.Assert(!switch2)

Comment: @NikolajBjorner The switches (several hundreds, for every assembly instruction one) and the constants are the things I retrieve from the model. This way the solver 'generates' an assembly program that meets certain constraints (in the example rax!1==0), but I don't know how to prevent the model from using certain constants (in the example rax!0, initial register states). I don't know which switches to asserts, because, then I already know the asm program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model/interpretation is typically defined as a total map from symbols to values; it therefore seems a bit surprising if one could tell the solver to not include certain symbols in the assignment.

Here is an idea, though: I interpret your goal of finding models that "ignore" certain symbols as finding models which remain models regardless of which (other) values one would assign to the symbols of interest. That is, models that work for all values of these symbols. Hence, you universally quantify over these symbols and then ask the solver for satisfiability.

Consider this example:

```
(declare-const b1 Bool)
(declare-const b2 Bool)
(declare-const i1 Int)
(declare-const i2 Int)

(assert
  (or ; Admits several models
    (not b1)
    (< 0 i1)
    (and b2 (= i1 i2))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

It admits several models, e.g. `i1 = 0, i2 = 0, !b1, !b2`. If you want to enforce models that "ignore" `i1`, i.e. which are models regardless of the value of `i1`, then simply quantify over `i1`:

```
(assert
    (forall ((i1 Int)) 
      (or
        (not b1)
        (< 0 i1)
        (and b2 (= i1 i2)))))
```

The only way of satisfying these constraints is satisfying the first disjunct, for which the value of `i1` is irrelevant. Indeed, adding `(assert b1)` to above program makes it unsatisfiable: there are no models left in which `i1` can be ignored.

Quantifying over `i2`, on the other hand, leaves the solver with a greater choice of potential models: those in which `i1` is irrelevant (because `!b1`) and those in which `i1` is positive.

Comment: Quantifying over irrelevant constants does indeed solve my problem. Hadn't thought about that. Thanx!